# Auto format/beautify UIPath workflow design

Tags: uipath

It seems like there's no functionality in UIPath Studio to auto format a workflow. i.e., like the formatting option in a control flow/data flow in SSIS.

Is that correct? :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no build-in functionality for that in the UiPath Studio 2018.4 version or below. I looked after a nuget that does this, but did not find anything. 
If your workflow gets too complex consider a different approach as using the **REFramework** template and extract **Sequences** as workflows where possible. From personal experience I can say that this will make your project more readable.

Comment: This is a very good comment. There is indeed no function like in LabView or Simulink to organise blocks or clean code.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a feature called "Auto Arrange" in UiPath.

Right click anywhere on the workflow > choose 'Auto Arrange'. it will arrange the control flows quite decently. Thanks